# Visual Studio shows exclamation mark in Assemblies

Tags: xamarin, mobile, native

**Mono.Android** ,**System.Web.Extensions** and **Xamarin.iOS** under Project Dependencies are marked with a yellow triangle and exclamtion mark anyone knows about this ?
[check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW3pP.png)

Comment: Why do you have the reference of Mono.Android and Xamarin.iOS in the same project?

Comment: Check the  Xamrin.Forms vesrion. You should be use proper vesrion of library.

Comment: @G.hakim it's auto generated

Comment: @ramyabr how can I do that?

Comment: What project is this? PCL/.Net Standard? Android or iOS?

Comment: @G.hakim it's a xamarin mobile app

Comment: What project is this?

Comment: It's a mobile project created with xamarin

Comment: You can remove Mono.Android and Xamarin.iOS .It is not required in the core part.

Comment: Do you have any problem with opening the project in the solution?

Comment: @ramyabr no i don't have any problem opening the project, i just want to make sure that everything is fine